# Cannot Rotate Legend Horizontally in GeoPandas

Tags: matplotlib, legend, orientation, geopandas

I am trying to plot California counties and color them by their FIPS code.  The sample code from the GeoPandas website is:

```
chicago.plot(
    column="POP2010",
    legend=True,
    legend_kwds={"label": "Population in 2010", "orientation": "horizontal"},
)
```

That code works.  My code is

```
ca_counties.plot(column='COUNTYFP',
                 legend=True, 
                 legend_kwds={"label": "FIPS", "orientation": "horizontal"},
                )
```

That code returns an error message that `TypeError: Legend.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'label'`.  Unless I am going crazy, the spelling of "orientation" is correct and everything else matches.  I have also removed the comma after the `}` but that does not work.  I am able to plot `ca.counties` with the "FIPS" label as well as use the ``loc" keyword to move the legend around.  It is only when I try to change the orientation that I have a problem.

Since the chicago example works, I do not think it is something with the version of `geopandas` and `matplotlib` I have installed.  I updated them anyway.

In case it matters, I am using JupyterLab via Anaconda Navigator.  The error exists whether I execute the code from the cell or paste it into the console and execute in the console.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Does the sample code from the GeoPandas website work in your environment? Please test this first.  Maybe you have a different GeoPandas (or matplotlib) version?

Comment: Would it be possible to create a fully reproducible example? Including all the imports. Are you sure `ca_counties` and `chicago` have exactly the same data type? Also note that matplotlib's legend doesn't accept a `label` parameter.  Did you try to leave it out? Does your code work well when you leave out the `legend_kwds`? Or to change it to `title`? Could you add a hyperlink to the example code you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to make a MWE script and in so doing figured out the problem.  `COUNTYFP` was an object dtype, so matplotlib was creating discrete colors.  For a reason I don't understand, `orientation` only works for colorbars.  Chaning `COUNTYFP` to numeric data solved the problem.